# Movement of objects in game

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a queston about movment of object in app (game) I am creating. I tried move ImageView with timer. So every 0.01 second object move for 1px. But movement is not smooth. So i also tried with animations. But there is problem, that if I close app and run it again (app was stil opened in background), there are problems, that picture of View stays on the end of animation. And also I want to check every 0.01 second if moving object and my character did colide, so animation is not the best option. Is there a way to move my object smooth with local time on phone? Or there is some other way to move object?

Comment: It sounds like you're not using SpriteKit or any game engine for that matter. Any game engine will come with an update loop that does all of this.

Comment: Even if you don't use any game engine whatsoever (e.g., OpenGL ES or even UIKit itself), you can set up an CADisplayLink instance, have it call you back on every frame refresh, and query how much time passed since last frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not using SpriteKit or any game engine for that matter. Any game engine will come with an update loop that does all of this.

You can learn about SpriteKit here... http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners